# Is SetFocus a Function?

Tags: vba, ms-access, setfocus

I saw this line of code `txtNewCaption.SetFocus` and was told that `SetFocus` is used as a sub
here but it is also a function. I also read online that the difference between a sub and a function is that a sub doesn't return any value but a function returns a value. I couldn't imagine what kind of value `SetFoucs` could return, so I searched quite some articles online about `SetFocus` but none of them gave me an example of `SetFocus` used as a function to return a value. I am assuming there is something inaccurate or wrong with either my understanding or what I was told.

Could you please help me to clarify the confusion?

Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-objects-properties-methods-and-events

Comment: Please consider __voting__ to [rate answers as (not) helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this case and example, .setFocus is not a sub, nor is it a function.

A sub  is a separate bit of code, you call it like

```
Call MySub
```

(or a shorter form skips the word "call" - it is optional)
eg:

```
MySub
```

Or, if there are parameters, you might go:

```
Call MySub(InvoiceNumber)
```

In the case of a function? That is again a external bit of code. You can use functions that return a value and IGNORE that return value.

So

```
MyVar = MyFunction()
```

And just like subs, the function can accept parameters:

```
MyVar = MyFunction(InvoiceNumber)
```

And as I noted, you can "ignore" the return value of a function like this:

```
MyFuncton  InvoiceNumber
```

If you write as per above, the you are passing the value, but the return value of the function is not "placed" or put into anything. so you can "use" a function that returns a value. You also skip use of the () around the value you pass.

However, in the above two examples we are talking about VBA sub and functions YOU write.

SomeTextBox.SetFocus is NOT  sub, nor is it a function.

What the above is called? It is called a Method of the object.

So, when you use Access objects, say record Sets, controls etc? Well that "object" will have what we call properties (usually things that you can set or get a value from).

So, for a text box, you have:

```
MyControl.Value = "Hello"
```

The above would set the value (text) of a text box to Hello. Thus ".value" is the property of that text box. It also happens to be the default property. So you can go:

```
MyControl = "Hello"
```

Now, if you go:

```
 Msgbox("Value of MyControl = " & MyControl.Value)
```

So a property of a "thing" (a object) often can be set a value, and you can get (retrieve) a value. This is called a property.

However, these objects also have what are called methods. Methods are a "action" and are similar to a sub/function (but YOU did not write that method).

And such methods are "some code" that runs that is part of the object. So sometimes the difference between a property of a object, and a method of a object  is "gray". Some methods can accept values and return values, but the distinction between the two (method and property) is that MORE then setting a value can occur with a method. (so it not just limited to get and set).

A "method" can be thought of some "action" and code. Use of that Method tends to be assumed that some code will run. (and it not your code in most cases - it is "code" attached to the built in object.

So

```
MyTextBox.SetFocus
```

It is a method of the text box control, or the given control in question. Not all controls necessary may have this "method".

So .SetFocus is not sub, not a function, but is in fact a method of the control in question.

Comment: Very comprehensive explanation that differentiates well. Since it became very long, some headings would give structure. Maybe even a `TL;DR` would summarize on top :-)

Comment: Isn't it both (method, type is sub)? E.g.  Application.BuildCriteria is a method too, but type is function.

Comment: As I stated, it can get somewhat "gray". The main difference between a method and a property comes down to does setting (or getting) a value also cause some kind of OTHER action. So, you might set the recordPointer, and that not only allows you to get (or set) the record pointer, but ALSO causes the recordset to "move" to the given record. So while both properties and methods "often" allow a set and get of a value, the distinction is that a method also does something MORE then just a get/set of a value.  Often a method is labled as a property and vice versa. But the distinction is a "action".

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Functions don't necessarily have to return a value. You can call functions just like you can call subs. Try for yourself: write a function, step through the function in a sub, and then check your locals window.

Functions have the added bonus of being able to return values, but don't have to.

EDIT: Aside from the need to return a value, I'm sure there is a reason to use one over the other, but I generally determine whether to use a sub or a function by the complexity of the task. I use functions to perform simple tasks and subs to perform more complex ones.

Comment: Question is to return, or not to return sth. (without ByRef) https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/4805/introduction-to-procedures

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

If you [search the **Microsoft Documentation (MSDN)**  for `SetFocus`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=SetFocus&ac=8), you will find it defined as:

> **method** on a user-interface control object, moving the focus to it ... with **no return value**

*(above quotation is not literally cited, but conveys the meaning)*

- [SetFocus Method [Access 2003 VBA Language Reference]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa221598(v=office.11))
- [TextBox.SetFocus method (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.TextBox.SetFocus)
- [SetFocus method (Microsoft Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/setfocus-method)

#### Function?

Thus it is not a *function* in VBA syntax.
Besides: a **function's return value** in VBA **is optional**. See [VBA language reference: Function statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement):

> Optional. Return value of the Function.

#### Common method naming conventions

In most programming languages the common **naming convention** (case ignored) for methods apply:

- use `get` (often without parameters) to return a value. Such methods are called *getter* or *accessor*.
- use `set` (often with parameter as value to set) to set a new state (or value). Usually the have no return value, because the new value or state is predicted by the argument passed (their parameter). Such methods are called *setter* or *mutator*.
- use `is`, `has`, `exists`, `contains`, `starts`, `ends`, etc. to return a *boolean* value. Such methods are used to check flags (on/off, true/false, yes/no).
- use `calculate`, `locate`, `indexOf`, `find`, `fetch`, `lookup`, `determine`, etc. (often with parameters) to return a value resulting of some processing based on specified parameters (by some logical, mathematical algorithm or queried by data-retrieval)

Comment: Thank you for your help!